# How to get last value of split string-array? [VB.net]

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string

Alright so I have this:

```
Dim OldString As String = "Word<>Car<>Test<>"
Dim NewString As String() = OldString.Split("<>")
```

Now I want to get the last value of OldString, which would be "Test", just before you ask,
the last "<>" after "Test" has to be there, no matter what. Everytime a new string would
get added to the array, it would add "VALUE<>", in my case there's no way around it.

I only need the last value, but without knowing how many values the string-array has,
means I cannnot do something like `NewString(2)` or similar, since I don't know how many
values the string-array has...

I am stuck and I've been trying things for hours, I hope you guys can help me out, thanks!

Comment: Your split doesn't do what you think it does. This is a great example to have option strict on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix your split statement:

```
Dim NewString As String() = OldString.Split(New String() {"<>"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

You can loop through the NewString arrary like this:

```
For Each lstrString as String in NewString

    if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty(lstrString) = False) then
       Console.WriteLine("This is a value: " + lstrString)
    end if

Next
```

'Get the length of NewString like this

```
Dim lngth as integer = NewString.length()
```

'Get the last value

```
Dim lstrLastValue as string = NewString(lngth - 1) 'Or maybe -2 in your case
```

Comment: The result of looping through the array where these values:

`Word
>Car
>Test
>`

When I try to get the last value with the code you provided, I get this:

`>` for `lngth -1`
`>Test` for `lngth - 2`

Comment: Updated code.  Your split statement is wrong.  Split takes a single character, you need to convert it to a string for multiple characters.

Comment: In ruby "-1" accesses the final item in an array...is there anything like this in vb.net?